# How to keep column order same in dynamic pivot

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have below mentioned table :

```
drn RecNum  Name            Value
----------------------------------------------
1   1       ad1_pk          1
2   1       ad1_address1    P.O. Box 5036
3   1       ad1_address2    NULL
4   1       ad1_address3    NULL
5   1       ad1_ctyfk       56
6   1       ad1_postalcode  80155-5036
7   1       ad1_active      Y
8   1       ad1_irstat      A
9   1       ad1_irdata      NULL
10  1       ad1_at1fk       1
1   2       ad1_pk          2
2   2       ad1_address1    1871 S. Broadway
3   2       ad1_address2    NULL
4   2       ad1_address3    NULL
5   2       ad1_ctyfk       1
6   2       ad1_postalcode  80210
7   2       ad1_active      Y
8   2       ad1_irstat      A
9   2       ad1_irdata      NULL
10  2       ad1_at1fk       1
```

I am creating the pivot using the below mentioned query:

```
declare @var nvarchar(max)
declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @var =  stuff((select distinct ',' + name from temp
                        for xml path('')),1,1,'') -- **this is giving distinct column list but the order of columns get changed..**

set @sql = 'select * from temp
pivot(max(value) for name in (' + @var + ')) as pvt'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Is there a way to keep the order of the columns unchanged? I want the order of columns listed in `@var` to be same as in the table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a `GROUP BY` and an `ORDER BY` clause (to replace the `DISTINCT`) where you build your column list as follows:

```
set @var =  stuff((select ',' + min(name) from temp GROUP BY drn ORDER BY drn
                        for xml path('')),1,1,'')
```

And don't forget the the necessary aggregation (I've used MIN()). Thanks @Ionic.

Comment: Well sure? Group By drn, but no aggregation on name? This should throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you're using a `DISTINCT` in your `SELECT` query. If you look at the execution plan, you can see `DISTINCT SORT` operation. This sorts your result based on the `DISTINCT` columns you specify, in this case it's `Name`:

[image]

To retain the order, you can try this:

```
set @var =  stuff((
                select ',' + name 
                from(
                    select
                        name,
                        drn,
                        rn = row_number() over(partition by name order by drn)
                    from temp
                )t
                where rn = 1
                order by drn
                for xml path('')),
            1,1,'')
```

Comment: Calculating rn in your query will give same results as column - Recnum.  this will be duplicating the data.